# selenium webdriverでのページ遷移

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

WebDriverを使用し、ログイン画面にてログイン後、
そのブラウザのページで別のページに遷移したいのですが、遷移しなく困っております。

以下ソース

```
ログイン関数
    static void login(IWebDriver _webDriver){
            _webDriver.Url = "url1";     //
            IWebElement loginID = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("login_id"));
            IWebElement password = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
            IWebElement submit = _webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("classname"));
            loginID.SendKeys("loginID");
            password.SendKeys("password");
            submit.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
        }
```

上記処理後に
以下の関数を呼び出します。

```
ページ遷移関数
    static void nextPage(IWebDriver _webDriver){
            string url = "url2";
            _webDriver.Url = url;
            //_webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }
```

以下main関数の処理となります。

```
mainの処理
　　static void Main(string[] args)
        {     
            IWebDriver ie = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            login(ie);
            nextPage(ie);
        }
```

ページ遷移関数は処理は通り、エラーもでないのですが
遷移しない状況となっております。

IWebDriver ie = new InternetExplorerDriver();
をそれぞれの関数の中で宣言してみたらどちらもページは
開くのですが、ページが別れて開かれてしまい、url2はログインしないと
開けないページなのでログインしてくださいとでてしまいます。

どなかたご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら
回答お待ちしております。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

```
IWebElement submit = _webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("classname"));
```

これはsubmitボタンでしょうか？

```
submit.Click();
```

では動かないですか？

Answer (score 0):

login() 単体では動いてるんですか？

※ 既にコメントがついていますが、僕も「ボタンはクリックするべき」だと思います。

login() 単体で動作している（ように見えている）と仮定して、「（サーバサイド及びブラウザの）ログイン処理の完了」の待ち合わせが不足と思います。

認証情報を submit した後に「ログインの完了」を確認してから、login() を抜けるべきです。